# Does it help if I delete the questions based on bad practices?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

As far as the rules of the site, I try to follow but in some situations either I miss something, or I get desperate and get negative points and criticism. Well, not complaining about that, because I know the purpose of the site and its rules.

Does it help if I delete the post that is not following good practices so it doesn't... well, I don't know... bother other users, and to not let "taint" the knowledge base that I know the site it's trying to be?

Comment: You can't delete a question that has upvoted answers, if you're talking about your most recent question.

Comment: So, basically there's nothing I can do, right? I read the rules, seriously, but I make this mistakes from time to time, so... what can i do?

Comment: Good question. Maybe revise the question description to account for lessons learned? Sometimes I learn after asking a question and responding to comments, I realize that my question had a bad premise -- or I wasn't aware of a foundation technique that made my question irrelevant. I'm still not sure what the official recommendation is for situations like that.